# Include <string> in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, string, include

I cannot understand why if I use std::string objects in Visual Studio 2010, sometimes it happens that the inclusion of string through the directive:

`#include <string>`

is necessary, while some other times it is not required.
Could anyone simply explain me why? Which is the ratio behind it?

Tnx in advance

D.

Comment: Some other file you're including is including it. Remember that `#include` means "insert the contents of this file here" and nothing smarter than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can never be a case where you're accessing std::string without including header file for that. In your case some other file might be including string in it.